# How to connect local MongoDB Compass to a third-party VPS Mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, ssh, vps, mongodb-compass

I have a remote Virtual Private Server (VPS) running Linux CentOS on which MongoDB has been installed by my service provider.  I've long hosted websites there, but I am new to MongoDB.  I am able to access that VPS via my local terminal.

I SSH into the server with this simple command, without requiring a password because I have a public RSA key in the server's `.ssh` directory:

`ssh sshusername@111.111.111.11`

If I specify a port, I am then prompted for a password to SSH in:

`ssh sshusername@111.111.111.11 -p22`

Either way, I am connected and able to work with my Mongo database on that VPS starting with this command, which prompts for a password:

`mongosh --username mongousername --password`

I can create users and the basics via command line.  That's not an issue.

**What I need help with is that I want to be able to work with this database via the GUI in MongoDB Compass**, but I can't figure out how to configure Compass in order to make the proper connection.  It never connects and I keep getting "socket closed" errors.  I've tried several ways and can't figure it out.  I've tried doing it with usernames and passwords (both for my SSH connection and the MongoDB users), as well as uploading the matching private key for the public one on my VPS.  I've tried using passwords and the key at the same time.  I've tried with TLS on and off.  I can't can't find clear documentation for what I need to do.

I guess I need to come up with the correct URI and/or Advanced Connection Options in Compass.  I started with this for the URI, tried including the port, and have played around with a bunch of different connection options, as I mentioned above.

`mongodb://111.111.111.11`

I presume I will need to save multiple connection presets for multiple users, because my admin user can only change other users (if I understand correctly) and the other users are the ones that actually manipulate various databases.  Is this correct?

Any and all help appreciated, as well as any pointers or tips to better get me going.  Thanks.

Comment: Compass's [SSH Tunnel Connection Options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/connect/advanced-connection-options/ssh-connection/) don't work for you if set properly?

Comment: I don't know what "set properly" would be, that's kind of my question here, but yes, I had tried that.  I tried again just now, because the doc you linked explained using a FQDN for SSH Hostname (I had been trying the IP address there previously).  Is there anything on the other tabs I'd need to fill out in addition to the Proxy/SSH tab?  I did fill in the URL field as I mentioned above: mongodb://111.111.111.11  Plus, I just tried with TLS both on and off

Comment: Wouldn't the `SSH Hostname` just be `111.111.111.11`?

Comment: ... and the `URI` be `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`?

Comment: YES!!  That did it.  Thank you so much!  I was really beating my head against the wall with this.  I was getting confused as to how the bridge from SSH to Mongo should happen.  It felt like I was trying to SSH in and then unclear on how to make the additional connection to Mongo in the Compass settings.  Using the localhost IP for the URI is what I needed.  Setting the SSH Hostname to the IP as I originally had it, too (it's not a FQDN after all).  And apparently, I had to set TLS to default rather than "on".  Not sure whether that's a security vulnerability or not.

Comment: If you want to put your comment as an answer, I will happily mark it as *the* solution.

Comment: I guess I have additional questions...  When I use terminal to SSH into my VPS and then open Mongosh, I get a message that "Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted."  I need to lock that down.  I have an admin user and a regular user.  I was just able to use Compass to get in like this, I think, because access control is not enabled.  If it is enabled, where do I put the credentials in Compass?  In the Authentication tab?  Also, can I enable access control via Compass because I've not figured out how to do it via terminal?

Comment: If you have additional questions about _Authentication_, it's better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing/*"explaining"* the comments:

With my naive notion of how applications connect to a server through an SSH tunnel, I think of *"What gets me through the tunnel?"* and after I'm there, *"What connects my app to the server?"*.

You already did those steps manually.

`ssh sshusername@111.111.111.11` got you through the SSH tunnel (and gave you a commandline shell).  So, the app (MongoDB Compass) needs to know how to do that too.  Setting MongoDB Compass's `SSH Hostname` to `111.111.111.11` (and any other SSH parameters you want/need) gets you through the tunnel.

`mongosh --username mongousername --password` connected the app (`mongosh`) to the server (from the commandline shell).  MongoDB Compass (after getting through the tunnel) needs to do the same thing.  That corresponds to a (basic) `URI` of `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`.

Comment: Thank you.  I was close but was just short of understanding this.  I do now